# How to apply translation and transformation to a label while keeping the label text left justified

Tags: ios, swift

I have a label and a text input where when the user loads the initial page, the label is on top of the text input box. When the user clicks on the label, I want the label to move up above the text box and also reduce the point size of the text in the label. The user can then type text into the text box. If the user does not type anything in the text box and clicks somewhere else on the page, the label moves back down over top of the text box and sets the text size back to the original size (this part works)

To perform the translation, I am trying to reset the constant value of the label's top auto constraint and the label's leading auto constraint. The label moves up correctly to the correct position above the text box when the animation is run, however, the label since I am transforming to 75% of the original size of the label, centers the now smaller-label thus making it move to the right instead of remaining pinned to the left edge like I want.

```
        func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let thisItem = item as? CardInfoTextInputViewModelItem else {
            return
        }
        if let labelText = formLabel.text, let placeHolderText = thisItem.placeHolderValue {
            if labelText == placeHolderText {
                formLabel.text = thisItem.label
                textField.text = "" // blank out the text field
                formLabelTop.constant = 20
                formLabelLeading.constant = 0
                performAnimation(transform: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.75, y: 0.75))
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * done editing text field
     */
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard let thisItem = item as? CardInfoTextInputViewModelItem else {
            return
        }
        if let text = textField.text, text.isEmpty {
            formLabel.text = thisItem.placeHolderValue
            formLabelTop.constant = 38
            formLabelLeading.constant = 16
            performAnimation(transform: CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1))
        }
    }

    // perform the animation
    fileprivate func performAnimation(transform: CGAffineTransform) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1, options: .curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.formLabel.transform = transform
            self.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: nil)
    }
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach or if I need to approach this differently. I would like to know how to keep the label left justified once it has been translated up above the text box. Any help would be appreciated
Thank you
Brian

Comment: Just use https://github.com/Skyscanner/SkyFloatingLabelTextField or https://github.com/raulriera/TextFieldEffects

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that